# Infinite product for a generalization of gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, infinite-product

Is there a generalization of Weierstrass infinite product to the function

$$ \frac{1}{g(x,a)}=xa^{-x}e^{\Psi (a) x}\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{c_{n}(a)}\right)e^{\frac{x}{n+a}}$$

- $ \Psi(a) $ is the digamma function
- Whenever $a=1$ then $ g(x,1)=\Gamma(x) $
- The product if over the poles of the function $ g(x,a)$

So, is this a generalization of a weierstrass product of $ g(x,a) $?

Comment: How the $c_n(a)$ are defined?

Comment: $ c_{n} (a) $ are the poles of the function $ g(x,a) $ for a given 'a' real number

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But on the left side there is the reciprocal of $g$, so the poles of $g$ are zeros.

Comment: I still cannot grasp this kind of definition. Where are the poles of $g(x,2)$, for instance?